# Google maps KmlLayer times out and InfoWindow not showing

Tags: google-maps-api-3, kml

I have a google map embedded in a site that loads a kml file at https://www.getstable.org/who-can-help/therapist-map-kml using KmlLayer. Sometimes the map doesn't load up, I presume because google maps has a strict timeout, and often some of the pins on the map aren't clickable but some are with no clear reason why. Does anyone know what the timeout limit is on kmlLayer and how to increase it? Also is there any reason why sometimes some of the pins aren't clickable (ie no InfoWindow appears when you click a pin and the cursor doesn't change to a hand)?

Here's the code that shows it (some of the fields are templated):

```
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 856px;height: 540px;">Loading...</div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{protocol}://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var the_map = {
                options : { 
                        zoom:{embed:zoom_level},
                        center:new google.maps.LatLng({embed:latitude},{embed:longitude}),
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                },  
                geocoder : null,
                map : null,
                init : function() {
                    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

                      $('#map_canvas').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
                        window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
                        return false;
                      });
                },                  
                load_map : function() {
                    this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), this.options);

                        query = encodeURI('{site_url}{embed:map_url}');                     
                  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(query,{
                      preserveViewport:true
                  });
                  ctaLayer.setMap(this.map);      
                }
            }
            $(document).ready(function() {
                the_map.init();
                the_map.load_map();
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Servers have an unspecified timeout, but testing shows it to be 3-5 seconds. This timeout is not something you can affect. The solution is to make your server respond faster. This issue almost always comes down to a file that is too big (yours isn't) or from dynamically generating the KML. You need to optimize this and that may mean finding a way to create a static KML file.

Features that are not clickable are almost certainly a problem with your KML. You can validate your KML to check for this:

- [Feed Validator](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=https://www.getstable.org/who-can-help/therapist-map-kml)
- [KML Validator](http://kmlvalidator.com/home.htm)

You can also test your KML by loading it at [maps.google.com](https://maps.google.com/?q=https://www.getstable.org/who-can-help/therapist-map-kml).

Comment: Thanks Chad. It does seem as if Feed Validator has a few issues with my feed so I'll look into that. It's odd that sometimes the same pin will work one day and then not work the next. It's a shame google has such a strict time limit.